# How to load the jar file defined in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object, jar

```
var obj;
try {
    obj = document.createElement("object");
    obj.id = "GameObject1";
    obj.name = "JavaGameObject1";
    obj.setAttribute("classid", "clsid:72E6F181-D1B0-4C22-B0D7-4A0740EEAEF5");
    obj.width = 640;
    obj.height = 526;

    var loginurl = document.createElement("param");
    loginurl.setAttribute("name", "loginurl");
    loginurl.setAttribute("value", "xx.xx.xx.xx:8080");
    obj.appendChild(loginurl);
    //append a lot of params here...

    document.body.appendChild(obj);
} catch (e) {
    alert("Exception:" + e.message);
}
```

I define a html object in javascript, and I want to load the jar after 'document.body.appendChild(obj);', but when the page was loaded, nothing happened.

Could you pls tell me why?

Comment: `data` and `type` attributes are missing in your code.

Comment: I have tried your code , and when I inspected the Html using firebug the element was there. Before posting questions try some thing yourself.

Comment: I visit the page on the set-top box, Not via pc browser. I think you could try iPanel browser, and nothing displays there.

Comment: To Uby: I have tyied this, but it doesn't work.